# Error: Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository

Tags: android-studio

Message Gradle Build:

```
Error:Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateRepository using TaskExecutionServices.createTaskArtifactStateRepository().
```

> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I've deinstalled Android Studio, clear all caches and try to invalidate caches and restart, nothing helps

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by CHMOD my project directory recursively :

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 project/*
```

In Mac OS I do also :

```
sudo chmod 0777 /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/gradle
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of the permission: `read, write, & execute for owner, group and others`.

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

I deleted the path /.gradle in my project-path

Comment: Hi, would you mind detailing the steps you took to solve this problem? I'm fairly new with Android Studio and don't know what you mean by "deleting a path in the project-path."

Comment: @Adrien on the left pane of android studio, there should be your project code and xml and so, click on android on the top and select project you will find .gradle folder, delete it then return back to android view, then hit build